# error in running a app in visual studio

Tags: xamarin

firstly I installed visual studio 2015 community. at the end of the installation the android sdk, ios and xamarin studio didn't downloaded correctly Message appeared.
then i was having an offline setup of xamarin studio only so i installed that successfully.
after that i created a new project by FILE->new project-> visual c# -> android ->blank app on visual studio.
now when i RUN it, there are many errors like :

Xamarin.Android for Visual Studio requires Android SDK. Please set Android SDK path on Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android Settings menu.

Since i installed only XAMARIN studio not android sdk, so can i install android sdk again externally just like i installed xamarin studio and if YES then How?

Comment: There is a separate installer you can download from Xamarin, https://www.xamarin.com/download

Answer (score 0):

Try Update All the SDK because your project may required higher SDK to build
In Xamarin Studio, Open Tools--->Open Android SDK Manager----->Then install what is missing